# How can I convert this code to Facebook SDK v4?

Tags: php, facebook

I need help how can I convert this code into SDKv4. Cause this code is not working already and giving me redirect loop or something about looping of redirects.

```
<?php 
require '../config.php';
require 'lib/facebook/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'     => $appID,
        'secret'    => $appSecret,
        ));

//get the user facebook id      
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){

    try{
        //get the facebook user profile data
        $getUserInfo = $facebook->api('/me');
        $params = array('next' => $base_url.'logout.php');
        //logout url
        $logout =$facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        error_log($e);
        $user = NULL;
    }       
}

if(!empty($user)){
//login url 

    $userInfo = $getUserInfo;
    $_SESSION['ses_id'] = md5(microtime());
    $buid = $userInfo['id'];
    $user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `scgfx_user_accounts` WHERE `fbid`='".$buid."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($user)>0) {
        $userdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($user);

        if($userdata['last_request_time']<=(time()-10800)) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `scgfx_chats` VALUES('','Welcome back to ".GLOBAL_NAME." <b>".$userdata['fbname']."</b>','0','global','".time()."')");
        }
        mysql_query("UPDATE `scgfx_user_accounts` SET 
                                            `gender`            =   '".$userInfo['gender']."',
                                            `ses_id`            =   '".$_SESSION['ses_id']."',
                                            `active`            =   '1',
                                            `sign_time`         =   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                                            `last_request_time` =   '".time()."',
                                            `ip_address`        =   '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' WHERE `fbid`='".$userInfo['id']."'");

    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `scgfx_user_accounts` VALUES('',
                                            '".$userInfo['id']."',
                                            '".$userInfo['name']."',
                                            '".$userInfo['gender']."',
                                            '0',
                                            '".$_SESSION['ses_id']."',
                                            '1',
                                            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                                            '".time()."',
                                            '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."','0','0')");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `scgfx_chats` VALUES('','We have a new member :) Welcome to ".GLOBAL_NAME." <b>".$userInfo['name']."</b>!<br/>Enjoy your stay!','0','global','".time()."')");
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['ses_id'])) {
        $getUserInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `scgfx_user_accounts` WHERE `ses_id`='".$_SESSION['ses_id']."'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($getUserInfo)>0) {
            while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($getUserInfo)) {
                $_SESSION['fbid'] = $data['fbid'];
                $_SESSION['name'] = $data['fbname'];
                $_SESSION['gender'] = $data['gender'];
                $_SESSION['acctype'] = $data['acctype'];
                $_SESSION['points'] = $data['points'];
            }
        } else {
                    die("Invalid Session ID");
        }
    ?>
        <script>

        window.close();
        window.opener.location.reload();
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}

else {
    $loginurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope'         => 'email,read_stream,offline_access,publish_stream,user_status,user_photos',
                'display'=>'popup'
                ));
    header('Location: '.$loginurl);
}
?>
<!-- after authentication close the popup  -->
```

I think this is the only way I can get this code working.

Comment: *Which part* of your code is the redirect loop occurring in?

Comment: Because everytime I click on the button to login to Facebook account, it always shows redirect loop. You can check my website on, www.pinoyinternetradio.com/chat

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

session_start();
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app-id','app-secret');
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('this-same-url');
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

if($session){
  $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
    $session, 'GET', '/me'
  ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

  echo "Name: " . $user_profile->getName();
  echo 'Token: ' . $session->getToken() . '<br/>';
} else {
  // Create here your login button
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginURL(array('public_profile,'));
  echo("Login URL:");
  echo($loginUrl);
}
```

Please note that this is a rough sketch and you should never echo the user token. For a more detailed explanation, please read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0